# Откуда лишний запрос при NTLM авторизации?

Tags: браузер, ntlm

Написал helloworld веб-сайт с basic аутентификацией, смотрю запросы в fiddler

Их два. Первый запрос -- это когда только открыл браузер (тебе сервер отправляет HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized и браузер в ответ на это показывает тебе окошко с вводом логина и пароля):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй запрос - это когда браузер отправил точно такой же запрос, но добавил в заголовок `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTI=` (где YWRtaW46MTI= - это base64 от логина:пароля):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё логично и понятно. Непонятное начинается, когда я смотрю запросы к тому же helloworld, но с NTLM аутентификацией: запросов становится три. Почему?

Первый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Третий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вообще так устроен протокол NTLM, что пароль в явном виде не передаётся и нужны несколько сообщений при обмене сервера и клиента.

В рамках протокола NTLM существует несколько видов механизмов «рукопожатий» (LM, NTLM, NTLM session security и NTLMv2), общая схема примерно такая (рис из [MS-NLMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc236621.aspx)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. есть:

а) фаза, когда клиент сообщает при помощи NTLM_NEGOTIATE, что он умеет в NTLM,
б) фаза, когда сервер отправляет NTLM_CHALLENGE (содержащий некоторый nonce - 16-битный фрагмент "случайных" данных)
в) фаза, когда клиент шифрует данные для входа с учётом nonce и отправляет их на сервер
(далее забота сервера связаться с контроллерами домена и проверить информацию)

Так вот если посмотреть скриншоты внимательнее, то всё так и было (сравни с [описанием](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc237488.aspx) в 4   Protocol Examples например 4.1   Server Examples):

на первом шаге сервер предложил использовать NTLM или более современный Kerberos (строчка WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на втором шаге клиент отправил NTLM_Negotiate и тут же в response получил challenge:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на третьем шаге клиент отправил NTLM_Authenticate и в ответ получил 200 ОК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При разборе подобных сообщений желательно посматривать в майкрософтовские спеки.

В первую очередь это то, как реализован NTLM поверх HTTP: [[MS-NTHT]: NTLM Over HTTP Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc237488.aspx) aka MS-NTHT.

Во-вторых, в этом документе идут постоянные отсылки на [MS-NNTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc236774.aspx) и [MS-NLMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc236621.aspx), в которых описываются конкретные форматы сообщений и хардкоженные константы (типа message_type = 0x00000001 - это NEGOTIATE_MESSAGE)

В-третьих, [общая страница майкрософт по NTLM](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/security/kerberos/ntlm-overview)