# Как принудительно выбрать NTLM, а не Kerberos в HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpclient

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Веб-сервер NancyFx с доменной авторизацией нормально отрабатывает из браузера, но не может работать с кодом на c# (этот код гарантированно рабочий, так как я проверял его на веб-сервере asp.net core с доменной авторизацией и там всё работает замечательно).

Код на c#:

```
public class WebRequestHelper
{
    public WebRequestHelper()
    {
        this.Client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public WebRequestHelper(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        var proxy = new WebProxy()
        {
            Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888"), // Fiddler
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        };
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
            Credentials = credentials,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            //Proxy = proxy,
        };
        this.Client = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; set; }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string uri)
    {
        return await this.Client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }

    public async Task<string> PostFormAsync(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        var response = await this.Client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string jsonString)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await this.Client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Когда я начал смотреть Fiddler'ом запросы - я понял, что причина почему не работает код заключается в том, что браузер аутентифицируется по NTLM ([проверял](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907298/213987)), а код на C# пытается аутентифицироваться по более новому Kerberos.

Как мне можно принудительно заставить код на c# аутентфицироваться по NTLM?

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл ответ самостоятельно: нужно использовать CredentialCache.

```
public WebRequestHelper(string userName, string password, string domain)
{
    var proxy = new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888"), // Fiddler
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    };
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

    var myCache = new CredentialCache();
    myCache.Add(new Uri($"{server}"), "NTLM", credentials);

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
        Credentials = myCache,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        //Proxy = proxy,
    };
    this.Client = new HttpClient(handler);
}
```

Работает и для сайта Nancy и можно отключить протокол в asp.net core (поправив appicationhost.config)

```
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <!--<add value="Negotiate" />-->
        <add value="NTLM" />
      </providers>
    </windowsAuthentication>
```

Открытым правда остался вопрос, почему nancy будучи сервером даёт на выбор клиенту два протокола (NTLM+Kerberos), при этом фактически не умея в Kerberos. Толи я накосячил с настройками nancy, толи не умеет протокол. Но это видимо отдельно ковырять надо будет.